# Nsdictionary Format issue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have the following answer(from server) in following format for Answer column in database.[image]

On updating the answer at app side and on saving it to database, it gets modified to the below format.(i.e, : is replaced by =) I would like to maintain the same format. Could someone let me know what is the issue? am using NSDictionary for accessing key value pair and am assigning final nsdictionary to DB. [image]

Comment: There is a difference between a Dictionary in JSON String representation, and calling `description` method of a `NSDictionary` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary and NSString containing JSON are not the same object, so they don't have the same format. When you are printing these object with an NSLog, it call the description method on theses objects. This method return the string for an NSString and a specific format string for a NSDictionary.

If you want to retrieve the JSON format, you need to transform your NSDictionary to JSON string again like following :

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
NSString *strJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"An error occured");
```

and then :

```
NSLog(@"%@", strJson);
```

I hope my english is understandable. Don't hesitate to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Larme pointed `-[NSDictionary description]` does not return JSON representation of dictionary. `NSArray` works in similar way.

Description of `NSDictionary` has the following format.

```
{
    key1 = value1;
    key2 = value2;
    ...
    keyN = valueN;
}
```

Description of `NSArray` looks as follow:

```
(
    object1,
    object2,
    ...
    objectN
)
```

In order to get JSON from dictionary you should use `NSJSONSerialization`(or third-party library).

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:response options:0 error:nil];
//Use line below to see formatted JSON
//NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:response options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]; 
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to have a NSJSONSerialization before passing it to NSSTRING

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:YOUR_OBJECT options:0 error:&error];


NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```